Spray Foam Near Recessed Lights
I'm about to install new canless recessed lights, but before drilling into the attic, I wanted to close a gap between an old ceiling and the new strapped ceiling to prevent any mice from getting inside so I used a low-expanding foam.
After I did it, I realized this could pose a fire hazard.
Did I make a dumb mistake and is there a way I could remedy it?
Thanks for any help.



Many canned lights and fixtures have information from the manufacturer regarding spacing or contact with insulation, so look there first. You may or may not have a problem.

Cut off a sample and set it on fire, and see what happens. I mean, outdoors in a controlled environment e.g. not California lol.  They do make less/non-flammable spray foam for nominally firestopping. Test it -- both the Sunshine Mine and the Browns Ferry nuclear plant accidents (and for that matter, Grenfell towers) grossly underestimated the flammability of the stuff, because nobody took a sample to a campfire pit and tried lighting it. Post10 has the right idea...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdItsso3ur0

I'll give that a try, thanks!

That foam plug will need to be removed simply because there is no room to place the light and driver box that comes with most LED canless lights.
Use the same tool you used for cutting the hole in the drywall and remove the foam. The light should be ok without anything on top of it.  The driver box if separate may need something like a scrap piece of drywall to sit on. Some have holes that allow mounting with screws to wood frame members.
As others stated, refer to the manufacturers instructions, but an  open area above the light is a given.

OP will also need to cut a channel for cable, no?

@Huesmann, assuming the foam does not go all the way to the roof decking.  If it does he will have to do that as well. Op stated that he foamed between the old ceiling and the strapped ceiling, so I'm thinking he has open area to run cable.

I meant simply getting from the cavity to the "attic" space.  OP will need to punch a hole and thread cable from the attic through the top layer of drywall to the cavity.  I suppose he could poke a wire through the old ceiling to get an idea in the attic where the cavity is, then bore a hole through only the old ceiling.

Thanks for the comments, the idea was to seal the gap between the new and old ceiling so potential mice couldn't get into the cavity after cutting the hole. I updated the image to show what it looks like now.

There are models of canless lights that could work. Especially ones which are designed for retrofitting into an existing can, the electronics box might be mounted on top or have some flexibility of mounting.

@Chester, You should be good to go with any LED canless light. there is open space for heat to rise and escape.
